# Kendo Grid Time Format Filtering

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, grid

I got Local Json data is

```
var MYDATA=[{"StartTime":'19:00:12.000',"StartDate":'2014-02-11',"Name":"John"},
            {"StartTime":'20:09:15.000',"StartDate":'2014-02-11',"Name":"Alan"},
            {"StartTime":'20:22:22.000',"StartDate":'2014-02-11',"Name":"Liza"}
];
```

I make kendo grid has properities are sortable,groupable,filterable,reziable. 
When I Try to filter to StartTime , it is not working. Can I put schema model field type is time?

```
StartTime:{ type:time}
```

If I dont define StartTime field in to schema model . Kendo grid thinks "it is string".

I define it date then defined it in column below;

```
 { field: "StartTime", title: "Start Time" ,format: "{0:hh:mm:ss}", filterable: {
                    ui: "timepicker",

                }}
```

But Not filter or Show in my grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to put it a "date". Valid data types are: "string", "number", "boolean", "date". The default is "string".

Valid type can be found in here : http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/model#methods-Model.define

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/B8G6X/

```
var MYDATA=[
    {"StartTime":'19:00:12.000',"StartDate":'2014-02-11',"Name":"John"},        
    {"StartTime":'20:09:15.000',"StartDate":'2014-02-11',"Name":"Alan"},
    {"StartTime":'20:22:22.000',"StartDate":'2014-02-11',"Name":"Liza"}
];

var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data : MYDATA,
    schema : {
        model : {
            fields : {
                StartTime : { type : "date" },
                StartDate : { type : "date" },
                Name : { type : "string" },
            }
        }
    },
    pageSize: 10
});

var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: ds,
    editable  : false,
    sortable  : true,
    pageable  : true,
    columns   :
    [
        { field: "StartTime", title: "Time", format : "{0:HH:mm:ss}" },
        { field: "StartDate", title: "Date", format : "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" },
        { field: "Name", width: 200 }
    ]
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

Comment: How can I filter StartTime ? How Can use filterable method?

Comment: Yes, you can. You will probably have to define for the field `StartTime` something like: `filterable: { ui: "timepicker" }`